# How to count pixels in a object mask which is segmented using Mask R-CNN?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, reference-request, object-detection

I have segmented concrete cracks from concrete structure images using Mask R-CNN. Now I need to measure the length of the segmented masked crack.

Will the pixel counting method work? Can anyone help?

Note: The images are taken at the constant distance from the object.